# src img shows black background and small white pixel at the middle

Tags: html

the black background can be seen inside link, image is not showing up..

[image: image not display]

the path is match with the link.. the picture I want to produce is 850 pixels width and 150 pixels height...

[image: path of image]

I have tried to paste the image at different folder but the problem is still there.. any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the folder permission - need to be 644 or 777

See if your image is real png format, open with image editor and save as png or jpg and try it.
hope it will help.

Comment: Hello, Ben Zvi.
Thank you for the feedback.. I will try your suggestion..

Comment: Thank you. You were right, the PNG file messed up.
Actually, I created my own picture using Photoshop and saved it as PNG. 
As how you suggested, I went to an online website and convert it to PNG, again.
Sounds silly but that works. Thanks. :)

Comment: Hey, I know this sounds off-topic but how you can check the permission? Both locally and live?

Comment: if you use FTP software like filezilla, point to the folder or file, right click and choose File Permission, you will see a small table with permission variation.

Comment: Re: Photoshop, you have to choose File > Save for the Web it will open new window where you can choose the format to save, like jpg, png 8 or png 24. these format will be compatible for website.

Comment: usually you don't need to mess with permission but if you want to know for local (pc) permission you have to use your regular File Explorer point to the file or folder you need and right click choose Properties > Security you'll see there the permission, you may want to check with your OS docs for detail. here's a windows link that explain it [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727008.aspx)